# > and < break json encode, how to encode propery?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Im trying to encode some html within json from PHP. The function requests data from a PHP file, and then will `append` it into the html page. The function works fine until I have < or > within the string I am trying to pass. This is my PHP code:

```
$append = "<b>Edit</b>";
for($i=0;$i<count($atarray);$i++)
{
    $append .= $atarray[0]['atname'];
}
$json = json_encode(array('ok' => '0', 'apso' => $append));
echo $json;
```

This works fine, if instead of `"<b>edit</b>"` I use `"Edit"`, is there a way to get it to work including the HTML tags?

The error that comes up in console is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.7.js:2` whenever I run the function.

JavaScript

I'm using the jQuery form plugin -> http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/form
It's sending the variables as `POST` data

but this is my function

```
$(function(){
$("#change").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit:function(before){
            $('#loadingsignup').show();
            $("#resultsignup").empty().hide();
        },
        success:function(retour){
            $('#loadingsignup').hide();
            res=jQuery.parseJSON(retour);
            if(res.ok==1){
                $('#resultsignup').append('<p class="good"><?php echo $lang['107']; ?></p>');
                if(res.img!==undefined){
                    $('#eaim').attr('src','/images/artistsprofilepic/'+res.img);
                }
            }else if(res.apso!==undefined){
                var ap=res.apso;
                $('#apso').append(ap);
            }else{
                $('#resultsignup').append('<p class="pasgood">'+res.err+'</p>');
            }
            $("#resultsignup").hide().fadeIn(500);
            setTimeout("$('#resultsignup').fadeOut();",5000);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen; JSON and HTML aren't related. What does your JavaScript look like?

Comment: Why are you trying to encapsulate XML into JSON, isn't there a better way to do what you want to do by just using or XML or JSON???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting rid of the call to `jQuery.parseJSON`, and use the option `dataType: 'json'`. `.ajaxSubmit` uses `jQuery.ajax`, which tries to figure out the format of the response, and it may have determined that it was JSON, so it was already parsed. Parsing it again results in this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but try adding this before your JSON echo (it should be there anyway).

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

This sets the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file, otherwise it'll default the content type to `text/html`, and I think that can confuse jQuery.

Also, as per the comments, please show the javascript you're using.

Comment: results in this error if i add that header `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://www.x.org/editataccount_check.php?ealid=72".`

Answer (score 1):

Set the response data type:

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
  dataType: "json",
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode them using `htmlentities()`

```
$json = htmlentities(json_encode(array('ok' => '0', 'apso' => $append)), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

You can also choose to just encode the values in the `$append` variable like so:

```
$json = json_encode(array('ok' => '0', 'apso' => htmlentities($append, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

Comment: I don't think this should be necessary - it smacks of working around a bug in the AJAX call rather than fixing it.

Comment: He is wanting to include HTML within a JSON response to an AJAX call, thus the HTML elements in the JSON response need to be encoded.

Comment: HTML does not need to be HTML-encoded within JSON.  If it does, something bigger is wrong.